# Can I safely delete calico-* pods from my cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

After updating container cluster node version to 1.7.6 new pods called calico-* appeared on my cluster. The question is - can I safely delete them?

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but those node appeared on my 2 clusters:

- first (my staging env), after update from 1.7.5 to 1.7.6
- second (my prod env), after update from 1.6.5 to 1.7.6

However, when I've created new cluster with version 1.7.5 and update it to 1.7.6 those pods have not appeared.

Mentiones pods are:

- calico-node
- calico-node-vertical-autoscaler
- calico-typha
- calico-typha-horizontal-autoscaler
- calico-typha-vertical-autoscaler

**edit:**

[image: disabled network policy]

Comment: Did you choose calico to be your virtual network overlay? In that case, those pods are essential for the overlay to work

Comment: I haven't chosen anything. I've created cluster with most values set to defaults and after the creation those pods where not there. They appeared after update version of nodes to 1.7.6. Furthermore with that setup I wan't be able to run my application on single node with 1 vCPU as all those default pods request in summary almost 100% of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calico is how Kubernetes network policies are implemented in GKE.
https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/network-policy-support-for-kubernetes-with-calico.html

I don't think it would be safe to delete them, if you did you very likely would end up with unreachable pods.

I thought it was necessary to specify `--enable-network-policy` when creating and even another extra step when updating a cluster.  Though maybe the components are always deployed but allow all policies are created if the flags are not specified.

**Edit:** If you delete calico pods they will be recreated and the add-on manager ensures there is no way to remove calico.

**Edit:** There is a command to disable network policy in GKE and the directions can be found at https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/network-policy#disabling_network_policy_enforcement.

Comment: OK, then how it is possible that my prod env lived without it up to version 1.7.5 and my staging env live without it at v1.7.6? All are reachable with no problems.

Comment: I've read the article and it seems that NetworkPolicy has been added in GKE in 1.7.6, however it sounds like it should be disabled by default. Certainly the behavior should be the same on all my clusters and it's not. Second thing - I understand that calico-node is involved in this, but not the other pods that I mentioned.

Comment: Typha is there to reduce the load on the K8s api server (necessary when scaling up the number of nodes and reduces the CPU usage in calico-node) and the autoscalers are there to ensure there are an appropriate number of typha instances and that calico-node and typha pods are appropriately sized.

Comment: @Seiya It was brought to my attention that there is documentation at https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/network-policy#disabling_network_policy_enforcement for disabling network policy enforcement.

Comment: Thank You Erik for the link. I will try to disable it (when the load on my app will be lower) and get back with results.

I'm curious of two things: 1) why this was enabled by default when I upgraded to 1.7.6, 2) what would happen (during upgrade) if I had my app deployed on single node at that time (all system pods requests almost 100% CPU)?

Comment: I haven't done it yet, but please see the attached screenshot in my first post. Network Policy has been already disabled there.

Comment: Hi Eric. After resizing my staging cluster from 0 nodes to 2, the calico pods reappeared. I've tried to disable network policy but it had no effect. I've even tried to enable it and disable it after that - no luck either. Do You have any other ideas? (I've also tried the steps above on version updated to 1.7.8 with the same result)

Comment: I don't really know what else to do, I'd probably submit a support issue to GKE.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Google provided a way to get rid of calico PODs via Google Cloud Console. Please see the screen below.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this "beta" feature. After creation, cluster does not have calico pods. It is possible though that they will be launched on first deployment of network policy.